# Single-word adjective meaning "of or pertaining to age"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am trying to emphasize diversity in a group of people by describing their backgrounds with the following adjectives:

*"...[they have] a wide variety of socio-economic, intellectual and religious backgrounds."*

Now I also want to add another adjective, to point out that members of this group also have significant variation in their age.

*"...[they have] a wide variety of socio-economic, intellectual, religious and **[adjective describing age]** backgrounds."*

Is there single-word adjective that would be appropriate here?

Comment: How is age a background?

Comment: I'm with @Lawrence on this one; even if there were such an adjective it wouldn't fit in this sentence IMO.

Comment: I'd probably say "[they have] a wide variety of socio-economic, intellectual and religious backgrounds, covering a large age range." (or range of ages)

Comment: @carouselambra "generational"?

Comment: The semantically nearest adjective I can think of that could conceivably be used in the desired spot in your original sentence is *eval* but it's not precise enough for the intended purpose. It's interesting that English doesn't appear to have an adjective that neatly captures the age attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***generational***

> generation
>
> The people born and living about the same time, considered as a group: *the baby-boom generation.*
>
> [AHDEL](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=Generational&submit.x=0&submit.y=0)

Comment: Accepted especially after seeing [this definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/generation?s=t): _"a group of individuals, most of whom are the same approximate age, having similar ideas, problems, attitudes, etc."_ This is exactly what I was trying to convey.